# PhoneGap javascript localStorage Android

Tags: javascript, android, database, cordova, local-storage

So I'm trying to test this in a PhoneGap application using this method:
http://inflagrantedelicto.memoryspiral.com/2013/05/phonegap-saving-arrays-in-local-storage/

I keep getting a reference error when the code gets to the:
*window.localStorage.setItem* and *window.localStorage.setArray*

JS:

```
Storage.prototype.setArray = function (key,obj) {
    return this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(obj));
}
Storage.prototype.getArray = function (key) {
    return JSON.parse(this.getItem(key));
}

var storedSettings = window.localStorage.getArray('mysettings');

alert('storedSettings = ' + storedSettings);
  if (storedSettings === null) {
      var settings = newArray();
  } else {
      var settings = storedSettings;
  }

$(document).ready(function() {



$('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
    alert('sup');
    var xsize = $('input[name=rads]:checked').attr('id');
    var xfirstname = $('#fname').val();
    var xsex = $('input[name=mf]:checked').attr('id');

    settings.push({'size':xsize, 'fname':xfirstname, 'sex':xsex});
    window.localStorage.setItem('mysettings', settings);
    window.localStorage.setArray('mysettings', settings);
    alert('settings:\n#1: ' + settings[0] + '\n#2: ' + settings[1] + '\n#3: ' + settings[2]); 
});



});
```

HTML:

```
<label for='small'>small</label>
<input type='radio' name='rads' id='small' checked='checked'/><br/>

<label for='medium'>medium</label>
<input type='radio' name='rads' id='medium'/><br/>

<label for='large'>large</label>
<input type='radio' name='rads' id='large'/>
<br/>
<br/>

<input type='text' id='fname' size='10'/>
<br/>

<label for='male'>M:</label>
<input type='checkbox' id='male' name='mf' checked='checked'/>
<br/>

<label for='female'>F:</label>
<input type='checkbox' id='female' name='mf'/>
<br/>
<br/>

<input type='submit' onclick='goset();' value='Save Settings'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

After some research, localStorage is enabled by default in PhoneGap.

I assume the reference error you're getting is due to this line:

```
var storedSettings = window.localStorage.getArray('mysettings');
```

Try checking to see if the array exists before calling it:

```
if(window.localStorage.getArray('mysettings') !== undefined){
    var storedSettings = window.localStorage.getArray('mysettings');
else{
    var storedSettings = [] /*default settings and/or empty*/
}
```

Comment: Would this go under the MainActivity.java file?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java or Android development, but I think that's the right path.

Comment: Hmm...I think you are on the right track I just don't know how to implement it. I added what I could to the java file (no errors), ran it, and got an immediate force-close.

Comment: Try what I included in the edit, I found that in another question related to phonegap.

Comment: Disregard my last answer. PhoneGap enabled localStorage in the webview by default. You were referencing the array before it was created in localStorage.

Comment: I still get "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Storage> has no method 'getArray'. The 'If' statement is at the top.